# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

In my Laravel Web Application I got following error in following Line. When Laravel Email Trigger

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

```
  $order=array();

  $order['contactname']=$customername;
  $order['contactnumber']=$cusconnum;
  $order['pickupaddress']=$request->input('pickupaddress');
  $order['deliveraddress']=$request->input('deliveryaddress');
  $order['pickupdate']=$request->input('pickupdate');
  $order['refnos']= $bookingpre."".$curbookingid;

  $myemail="karthik@w3cert.in";

  Mail::to($myemail)->send(new OrderBooked($order)); /* Error Raised Line */
```

following code for orderbooked mail

OrderBooked.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class OrderBooked extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;


    protected $order;


    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(array $order)
    {
       $this->order = $order;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {

    return $this->from('support@greatmovers.com.my')->markdown('emails.orders.booked') ->with(['contactname' => $this->order['contactname'],'contactnumber' => $this->order['contactnumber'],'pickupaddress' => $this->order['pickupaddress'],'deliveraddress' => $this->order['deliveraddress'],'pickupdate' => $this->order['pickupdate'],'refnos' => $this->order['refnos'],]);

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: That line should not cause an error - are you sure the problem is not coming from another class?

Comment: Post the code of `OrderBooked`

Comment: can you confirm the error came from that line only? by checking line numbers?

Comment: Please tell us the line number as well as filename. (Your error will stating both)

Comment: I Posted @linktoahref

Comment: hm maybe this space between `)` and `->`  `->markdown('emails.orders.booked') ->with` ?

Comment: Apparently this is caused by PHP 7.0, you need to update to 7.1+ https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/25986.

Answer (score -1):

You have unnecessary comma at the end of the following line just remove that.

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('support@greatmovers.com.my')->markdown('emails.orders.booked') ->with(['contactname' => $this->order['contactname'],'contactnumber' => $this->order['contactnumber'],'pickupaddress' => $this->order['pickupaddress'],'deliveraddress' => $this->order['deliveraddress'],'pickupdate' => $this->order['pickupdate'],'refnos' => $this->order['refnos']]);
}
```

Comment: Trailing commas in arrays is valid, it won't cause this error.

Comment: I've thought it caused syntax error just checked trailing comma are valid. I'll remove the post if it's not good @linktoahref

Comment: Same Error Display @SagarGautam

Comment: @Karthik can you add screenshot of error it would be easier to know

Comment: I Added the Screenshot @SagarGautam

Comment: What is your php version 7.0 ?